# Two Unicode fonts Mapping

Tags: fonts, unicode, mapping

I have certain text that I typed using Unicode (Devanagri input) I want to get output to a different unicode (Telugu) output.

I created a ".map" file and complied it with "teckit_compile". I created the .map file as shown below. Is there anything wrong in this.

```
LHSName "Devanagari"
RHSName "Telugu"
LHSDescription "Devanagari script"
RHSDescription "Telugu script"

pass(Unicode)

U+0901 <> U+0C01
U+0902 <> U+0C02
```

etc. etc. I got the mapping information from this site http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Comment: Please provide further information, how this exactly works, what "etc. etc." means, and what your question really is. Otherwise this question may be closed.